Spark expected output does not match actual output
Who can help me explain？
`I am learning spark, and this is what I am using for practice. I know this is not standard, but this is different from the output I expect.

            List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5);
            JavaRDD<Integer> parallelize = env.parallelize(list);
            JavaPairRDD<Integer, Iterable<Integer>> integerIterableJavaPairRDD = parallelize.groupBy(x -> x);


This is code.
The following is the calculation logic

            JavaPairRDD<Integer, Iterable<Integer>> aa = integerIterableJavaPairRDD.reduceByKey((Function2<Iterable<Integer>, Iterable<Integer>, Iterable<Integer>>) (integers, integers2) -> new ArrayList<>());
            aa.collect().forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));


I think the output will be:
(1,[])
(2,[])
(3,[])
(4,[])
(5,[])
But the actual output is as follows
(4,[4, 4])
(1,[1, 1])
(3,[3, 3])
(5,[5])
(2,[2, 2, 2])
`

I tried many times, no matter reduceBykey returns null, empty List or integers, the final output is the same as after groupBy

When each key is associated with only a single value, the reduce function within the reduceByKey operation might not perform any merging, as there are no additional values to merge for each key.
